# Duplicate tags: [utc] & [zulu-time]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Make [zulu-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zulu-time) a synonym of [utc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/utc). These refer to the same thing.

Comment: `zulu-time` has no questions tagged with it. Why keep it around?

Comment: I saw this when I was checking on new tags and fixed it strait away.

Answer (score 1):

[zulu-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zulu-time) does not have any questions so it will be removed within 24 hours; making it a synonym is not necessary.

Comment: I didn't realize this. I'll check tomorrow and make sure it was actually deleted.